# How to merge nested arrays of varying lengths, given they share an element in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, merge, flatten

I have nested arrays made up of strings and ints, of which I want to consolidate according to the first element of each array. Let's say these are item ids. The nested arrays are of varying length but as long as the first element of each nested array are the same, I want to merge them together.

My data might look like this:

```
arr = [['00', 'apples', nil, nil, 8],
['00', 'apples', nil, 2],
['00', 'apples', nil, nil, nil, 3],
['01', 'bananas', 2],
['01', 'bananas', nil, nil, 3],
['01', 'bananas', nil, 5]]
```

So I would like to condense these arrays so they look like:

```
arr = [['00', 'apples', nil, 2, 8, 3],
['01', 'bananas', 2, 5, 3]]
```

There won't be an instance where the second element (in this case apples or bananas) will be different for the given first element (00 or 01). So as long as the first element is the same between any two of the nested arrays, I want to merge them together.

Also, the data guarantees no collisions between the numbers for arrays sharing the same first element. However, the numbers should maintain their index positions post-merge. This is crucial.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this. I was thinking of creating an empty array and then iterating through the nested arrays checking to see if the first element is contained in the new array. If not, push that array to the new array. If so, merge them. The code I have doesn't work (I get an empty array)...

```
    new_array = Array.new
    old_array.each do |o|
      new_array.each do |n|
        if o[0] == n[0]
          n = o | n
        else
          n.push(o)
        end
      end
    end
```

I looked into `.reduce(:|)` but it gives me undesired results:

```
arr = [["00", "apples", nil, nil, nil, 8],
 ["00", "apples", nil, nil, nil, nil, 1],
 ["00", "apples", nil, nil, 1]]
arr.reduce(:|)
=> ["00", "apples", nil, 8, 1]
```

I was expecting: `=> ["00", "apples", nil, nil, 1, 8, 1]`

Comment: I inferred from your original example that the values in each resulting array are to be unique; e.g.,, at most one `ni!`.You need to edit to state precisely what you mean by "merge them together".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a hash and convert it to an array

```
new_hash = {}
old_array.each do |o|
  new_hash[o[0]] ||= []
  o.each_with_index do |n, i|
    new_hash[o[0]][i] ||= n
  end
end

puts new_hash.inspect
puts new_hash.map { |k,v| v }.inspect
```

This will result in

```
{"00"=>["00", "apples", nil, 2, 8, 3], "01"=>["01", "bananas", 2, 5, 3]}
[["00", "apples", nil, 2, 8, 3], ["01", "bananas", 2, 5, 3]]
```

Comment: Ruby has no method `merged`. That can't be a typo of `merge`, as `Hash#merge` requires a hash as its receiver. Also, the OP wants the result to be an array, not a hash. Lastly, note that the value of `"01"` contains `"01"`but the value of `"00"` does not contain `"00"`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Fixed the typos.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I just call `new_hash.values` in the end to grab my desired arrays. The code is a little confusing at first but makes sense after a second passover.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. One is to use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). Others may mention methods which merge hashes.

```
arr = [
  ['00', 'apples', nil, nil, 8],
  ['00', 'apples', nil, 2],
  ['00', 'apples', nil, nil, nil, 3],
  ['01', 'bananas', 2],
  ['01', 'bananas', nil, nil, 3],
  ['01', 'bananas', nil, 5]
]

arr.group_by(&:first).values.map { |a| a.reduce(:|) }
  #=> [["00", "apples", nil, 8, 2, 3], ["01", "bananas", 2, nil, 3, 5]]
```

These are the steps:

```
b = arr.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"00"=>[["00", "apples", nil, nil, 8], ["00", "apples", nil, 2],
  #           ["00", "apples", nil, nil, nil, 3]],
  #    "01"=>[["01", "bananas", 2], ["01", "bananas", nil, nil, 3],
  #           ["01", "bananas", nil, 5]]}
c = b.values
  #=> [[["00", "apples", nil, nil, 8], ["00", "apples", nil, 2],
  #     ["00", "apples", nil, nil, nil, 3]],
  #    [["01", "bananas", 2], ["01", "bananas", nil, nil, 3],
  #     ["01", "bananas", nil, 5]]]
c.map { |a| a.reduce(:|) }     
  #=> [["00", "apples", nil, 8, 2, 3], ["01", "bananas", 2, nil, 3, 5]]
```

The first element of `c` is passed to `map`'s block and assigned to the block variable:

```
a = [["00", "apples", nil, nil, 8], ["00", "apples", nil, 2],
     ["00", "apples", nil, nil, nil, 3]]
```

`a.reduce(:|)` gives the same result as `a.reduce { |d,e| d | e }`, which is merely the union of the three elements (arrays) of `a`:

```
(["00", "apples", nil, nil, 8] | ["00", "apples", nil, 2]) |
["00", "apples", nil, nil, nil, 3]]
  #=> ["00", "apples", nil, 8, 2] | ["00", "apples", nil, nil, nil, 3] 
  #=> ["00", "apples", nil, 8, 2, 3]
```

A similar calculation is performed for the second element of `a` passed to `map`'s block.

Comment: I was trying out these steps in irb and the `.reduce(:|)` is giving me a merged list but the elements are out of order. I edited my OP to show what I tried.

Comment: I like the explanation; very clear and concise. I learned a thing or two!